# Clicking "button" in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[Using Python 2.7 and Selenium Web-driver]

So there's this HTML code, which is kind of a button. How do I click it in Selenium?

```
<div class="PermalinkProfile-dismiss">
<span class="Icon Icon--close Icon--large"></span>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="permalink-overlay-body"]/div/div[1]').click
```

and

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="permalink-overlay-body"]/div/div[1]/span').click()
```

None of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define `None of them worked`. Is there any error? are you getting `elem` by the xpath?

Comment: Did you verify that your provided XPath `//*[@id="permalink-overlay-body"]/div/div[1]/span` is correct???

Answer (score 0):

`click()` is a function that doesn't return value, you can't assign it to variable. You can do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="permalink-overlay-body"]/div/div[1]/span').click()
```

Or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="permalink-overlay-body"]/div/div[1]/span')
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your selector is wrong. You can try other selection methods, for example `find_element_by_css_selector()`.

First find the element and see if it returns anything. Modify which `find_*` method you use and experiment with your selector patterns untill it matches - returns the element that you want.
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PermalinkProfile-dismiss span')

See [Locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) guide for possible aproaches here.

If you have the element than click on it:

```
elem.click()
```

As Guy stated `click()` doesn't return anything, so you need to do it in two steps.